# Assign a jQuery variable to a Rails session variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, assign

I have a simple select box with years and values 
like so

```
<div id="year_selection_area" class="controls text-center">
  <select class="form-control " name="Legislation year" id="dueYear">
    <OPTION VALUE='2017' >2017</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2016' >2016</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2015'>2015</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2014' >2014</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2013'>2013</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2012' >2012</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2011'>2011</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='2010'>2010</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE='' DISABLED>MORE YEARS ADDED SOON</OPTION>
  </select>
</div>
```

i also am assigning selected at the beginning through a mix of jQuery and rails

```
<% if session[:year_browsing]==nil%>
  <% session[:year_browsing] = 2016%>
<% else %>
  <%= session[:year_browsing] %>
<%end%>
<script  type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.form-control option[value=<%= session[:year_browsing] %>]').attr('selected','selected');
  });
```

however I need to change session variable depending on what user clicks
I tried an if/else statement but it executes all of the ruby as soon as it gets into that on change function

```
$( ".form-control" ).change(function() {
  alert( $(".form-control").val());
  var selectedValue = $(".form-control").val();

  if ( selectedValue=='2017'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2017 %>
  }
  else if ( selectedValue=='2016'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2016 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2015'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2015 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2014'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2014 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2013'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2013 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2012'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2012 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2011'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2011 %>
  }
  else if ( $(".form-control").val()=='2010'){
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 2010 %>
  }
  else{
    <% session[:year_browsing] = 0 %>
  }
});
```

Comment: you have to send a ajax method when you want to change session variable, you can not update session on views

Comment: I would suggest using browser local storage instead of session storage in order to achieve the same.

Comment: @Sebin thank you i posted my solution bellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you very much to Sebin (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1684772/sebin)

I ended up choosing to store it in browser storage with this code

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myVar = localStorage['myKey'] || '2016';
    $('.form-control option[value='+myVar+']').attr('selected','selected');
  });

  $( ".form-control" ).change(function() {
    alert( $(".form-control").val()) ;
    var selectedValue = $(".form-control").val();
    localStorage['myKey'] = selectedValue;
  });
</script>
```